# Windows XP system clock is always 5 minutes late

Tags: windows-xp

I have a Windows XP laptop and I've noticed that the system clock is always 5 minutes late. When I set the clock to the right time, by the next day it's...5 minutes late. What's going on here? Is the clock being synchronised with the clock of a server on the network somewhere? What can I do about this?

Comment: 5 minutes late compared to what? What are you using as your "zero point" reference for time? A desk clock, a cell phone, etc? How do you know that your "zero point" reference is accurate?

Comment: Just maybe the computer is correct and all your other timepieces are wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen very often if your computer is in domain. It basically means AD controller is out of sync and whatever you will set Active Directory will set it right back.

Answer (score 1):

You can also refer to this really well written guide for creating a Scheduled Task to help automate the resynchronization process.

http://www.pretentiousname.com/timesync/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is probably being sync'ed via NTP to time.windows.com or another time server.

If you are in a domain, and your computer is administered, you should not mess with this setting as you could risk losing access to network resources that rely on a synchronized time within the domain.

Microsoft has [the following KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314054) on how to set Windows to use its internal hw clock.

Hope this helps!

Comment: However, you can talk to your domain admins and have them get their system time synced up to a more accurate clock.